# How to create a dictionary of arrays in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a variable defined like this:

```
my_list:
  - key1: abc
    key2: xyz
    list1:
      - a
      - b
      - c
my_hash:
  a: p
  b: q
  c: r
```

In my playbook, I want to map list1 to it's corresponding entry in my_hash.
i.e. I want to get the end result as...

```
my_list:
  - key1: abc
    key2: xyz
    list1:
      - a
      - b
      - c
    list2:
      - p
      - q
      - r
my_hash:
  a: p
  b: q
  c: r
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get what I want. Really interested if someone can give a more optimized solution.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    mylist1:
      - key1: a
        key2: b
        mysublist:
          - x
          - y
          - z
      - key1: c
        key2: d
        mysublist:
          - t
          - u
          - y
          - z
    myhash:
      - hkey: t
        hval: testa
      - hkey: u
        hval: testb
      - hkey: x
        hval: testc
      - hkey: y
        hval: testd
      - hkey: z
        hval: teste
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        tempdict: "{{tempdict|default({})|combine({item.hkey: item.hval})}}"
      loop: "{{myhash}}"
    - set_fact:
        testvar: {}
    - set_fact:
        testvar: "{{testvar|combine({item.key1: []})}}"
      loop: "{{mylist1}}"
    - set_fact:
        testvar: "{{testvar|combine({item[0].key1: testvar[item[0].key1] + [tempdict[item[1]]]})}}"
      loop: "{{mylist1|subelements('mysublist')}}"
    - debug:
        var: testvar
```